# Does using abbreviated/vernacular spelling affect reading speed?

Tags: orthography, abbreviations

The spelling in an average text message is quite bad ('u'=you, 'r'=are, 'l8r'=later, etc), and intentional abbreviations are often used for space concerns. Has the effect of this on reading speed and comprehension been studied formally? [According to Elements of Style](http://www.booksofthedeadpress.com/2011/12/21-days-of-christmas-day-10-use.html) such abbreviations actually have a negative effect on reading speed, but there is no evidence given to support the claims.

Comment: It's an interesting question and I'm not aware of any research. If there is any it will have to take account of the differences between readers. I imagine that an avid reader of published texts would be slowed by the abbreviations whereas someone whose life revolves around texts and tweets would be slowed by the full spelling.

Comment: It's not about abbreviations as such, but about familiarity with the terms. If I see "u r 2 cm l8r" it takes me a while to figure out each element. My teenage niece would probably understand it much quicker.

Comment: Excellent, but very difficult content for someone's dissertation. I don't think it is about speed. It is more about trend and style.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be particularly about English.

Comment: That's an interesting take, since I cited a text which has, for decades, been the go-to style guide for English writing. It's definitely about abbreviations; many approved abbreviations are non-obvious: "no." or "#" for "number", "@" for "at", "c." for "circa", "est." for "established", "et al." for "and others", "etc." for "and so on", etc. ;)

Comment: First, _Elements of Style_ is **not** an authority on reading speed, or anything else. [Sorry, it's total BS](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497). Second, there is no standard for reading speed because there is no standard for reading. Reading, like driving or editing pictures, is a technology, not a natural phenomenon. Humans have evolved with spoken language and protolanguage for millions of years; there are genes involved. Reading in the sense you mean is less than 5000 years old -- no genes. So everybody learns to read their own way, and they're all different.

Comment: Yes, already read that amusing article. I didn't mean to imply it was a real authority. Actually the author admits that there is no authority for our language several times. But it is a de facto authority in academia: that's what I meant by "go-to". I'm not sure why you mention genetics, but I disagree that genes are not involved in reading, though. Reading comprehension, and to a lesser extent speed, is very obviously linked to at least one kind of intelligence.

Comment: @MattChambers Fair point. But looking at youngsters who read all those abbreviations and internet slangs faster than the old people (like myself), I don't necessarily agree with you. I don't think it is about intelligence nor genes. It depends on how much you accustomed yourself to those new abbreviations.

Comment: @Matt; If by "academia" you mean K-12 "language arts", then, yes, S&W is unfortunately authoritative for many otherwise sane teachers. As for genes, of course they're involved in everything we do. But not the same ones. The point is that everybody learns to read in their own way, with their  own resources, and their own experience, and their own theories. There simply is no uniformity in human reading, as there is in speaking; like any technical skill, some people are much better than others, and many never learn. If you average out everybody's behavior, you get nonsense. Like "intelligence".

Comment: abbreviations causing slower reading sounds reasonable to me, but I don't know of any studies. If you want good evidence, you could post the S&W claim on Skeptics SE.

Comment: Academia is K thru grad school, outside of English majors (I'd speculate). My current run-in with S&W is in a grad-level scientific communication course, which mainly focuses on clarity of communication (which has never been the norm in science, but hopefully will change).